# Переменные окружения в makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

Добрый день, возможно ли использовать переменные окружения в makefile?

Если возможно - приведите пример.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[разумеется, возможно](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html).

переменные окружения преобразуются во внутренние переменные программы, и к их значениям можно обращаться в форме `$(имя)`, а также переопределять эти значения стандартными средствами:

```
имя=значение
```

---

**стоит также добавить**, что внутри [рецептов](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Introduction.html#Rule-Introduction):

```
цель ...: пререквизит ...
  рецепт ...
```

которые выполняются оболочкой (а также и в правой части присвоений `имя=значение`, но не внутри целей или пререквизитов), к переменным окружения, так же, как и к переменным самой оболочки, можно обращаться точно так же, как это и просходит внутри программ оболочки. только требуется «удвоить» символ `$`, чтобы программа *make* могла отличить обращение к **своей** внутренней переменной от обращения к переменной оболочки:

```
$(x)  # обращение к внутренней переменной x программы make
$x    # альтернативная запись обращения к той же переменной,
      # допустимая в случае, когда имя переменной состоит из одного символа
$$x   # обращение к внутренней переменной оболочки x
$$xyz # обращение к внутренней переменной оболочки xyz
```